# Using TransformControls in Aframe scene results in an error

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to incorporate the THREE TransformControls into my Aframe scene but I get an error: "TypeError: tempGeometry.applyMatrix4 is not a function" on

```
var control = new THREE.TransformControls( cam, renderer.domElement );
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RogueSheep/p4te73oL/2/
Can anybody spot what I am missing here?

Comment: It seems this particular error disappears if you use the latest version of A-Frame. https://jsfiddle.net/yjfw5rgh/

Comment: Wow thanks @Mugen87! I guess that's what you get when working for old examples  ;-)
The error has been lifted, my journey can continue.